# Encontrar una palabra en una matriz

Tags: javascript, array, matrices, array-bidimensional

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio practico del curso de midudev que pide lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

LLevo varios días intentado algunas soluciones y he consultado varias páginas pero no consigo resolverlo, lo más lejos que he llegado ha sido esto:

```
  function findJavaScript(matrix) {
  if(matrix[0][0]==="JavaScript"){
    return [0,0]
  }else if (matrix[0][1]==="JavaScript"){
    return[0,1]
  }else if (matrix[0][2]==="JavaScript"){
    return[0,2]
  }else if (matrix[1][0]==="JavaScript"){
    return[1,0]
  }else if (matrix[1][1]==="JavaScript"){
    return[1,1]
  }else if (matrix[1][2]==="JavaScript"){
    return[1,2]
  }else if (matrix[2][0]==="JavaScript"){
    return[2,0]
  }else if (matrix[2][1]==="JavaScript"){
    return[2,1]
  }else if (matrix[2][2]==="JavaScript"){
    return[2,2]
  }else {
    return [-1,-1]
  }
}
```

Pero claro si el array es más largo no es posible esta solución:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentando hacer este codigo para recorrer filas y columnas:

```
function findJavaScript(matrix) {
  for(let i=0; i< matrix.length; i++){
        for(let j=0; i< matrix[i].length; j++){
            if(matrix[i][j]==="JavaScript"){
                return [i,j]
            }else{
                return [-1,-1]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*He probado con el indexOf y otros metodos de array pero no consigo encontrar la solución.
Gracias!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tenes 2 errores:

- La condición del segundo `for` dice `let j=0; i< matrix[i].length; j++`.
  Debería ser `j < matrix[i].length`
- Tenes que devolver `return [-1,-1]` cuando terminaste de revisar la matriz.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function findJavaScript(matrix) {
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
      if (matrix[i][j] === "JavaScript") {
        return [i, j]
      }
    }
  }
  return [-1, -1]
}

let matrix = [
  ['HTML', 'CSS', 'Nodejs'],
  ['PHP', '.Net', 'C++'],
];
console.log(findJavaScript(matrix));

matrix = [
  ['HTML', 'CSS', 'Nodejs'],
  ['PHP', '.Net', 'C++'],
  ['Python', 'Java', 'JavaScript'],
];
console.log(findJavaScript(matrix));
```

Comment: Gracias @Marcos, pero cuando hago el else no se supone que ya ha recorrido toda la matriz en el if? pregunto desde la ignorancia

Comment: Hola @PabloFC. La respuesta es no, donde habias puesto el `else` es justo en la primer comparación, cuando `i=0` y `j=0`, si ese valor era distinto, dejabas de buscar.

Answer (score 1):

esta ha sido mi solución:

```javascript
  function findJavaScript(matrix) {
  let position = [-1,-1];
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) { 
    for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)  {
    if (matrix[i][j] === 'JavaScript') {
      position.splice(0,2,i,j) 
      } 
    }
  } 
    return position 
}
```

Al principio usaba el método push para introducir tanto las coordenadas del elemento encontrado como el mensaje default en caso de no encontrarlo, pero siempre introducía demasiadas repeticiones.
Por lo que deje la posición default como valor inicial y lo modifiqué con las coordinadas que encontraba.

Answer (score 0):

Mediante un recorrido de filas y columnas con dos bucles for. El bucle c representa las columns y el bucle f las filas.

```
  const matrix = [
      ['html', 'css','react'],
      ['java','c++','python'],
      ['ruby', 'go','swift'], 
      ['javascript','Ruby','PHP']
  ];

   console.log( ' la matriz tiene columna ' + matrix[0].length + ' fila ' +  matrix.length ) ;

 function BuscarTexto( matrix, txtbuscar) {

   let txtrespuesta='';
   for(let c=0; c < matrix[0].length; c++){

      for(let f=0; f< matrix.length; f++){
      
         let elemento = matrix[f][c];
         if( typeof elemento === 'string' &&  
            elemento.toLowerCase() === txtbuscar.toLowerCase() ){
    
            txtrespuesta = "Encontre el texto '"+ txtbuscar + "' posicion: f= "+ f +" c= " + c ;
            return txtrespuesta;
        }   
    } // cierra for f  
} // cierra for c  

  txtrespuesta = "no se encontro el texto " + txtbuscar;
  return txtrespuesta;
 }

const result = BuscarTexto( matrix, "JavaScript" ) ;
console.log( result )
```

Modifique el script para que sea comprensible.

Comment: porque utilizas matrix[0] en el segundo bucle for? No se puedn añadir parametros a la función, solo debe recibir matrix

Comment: Para saber la cantidad de filas que tiene la matriz. con el indice cero

Comment: Te invito a leer [answer]. Responder sólo con código se considera de baja calidad, tu respuesta podría terminar reportada por ello y eliminada por el sistema.